Getting Error When Trying to Update a Model Using Objection
I am getting this error while trying to update a record in my model using objection.js.
The error I am getting is
Error: An error occurred while executing $setJson method. $setJson method was given an invalid value 1966
at setJson (node_modules/objection/lib/model/modelSet.js:13:11)
at UserDevices.$setJson (node_modules/objection/lib/model/Model.js:128:12)
at UserDevices.fromJson (node_modules/objection/lib/model/Model.js:264:11)
at UserDevices.ensureModel (node_modules/objection/lib/model/Model.js:584:25)
at UpdateOperation.onAdd (node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/operations/UpdateOperation.js:21:29)
at QueryBuilder.callOperationMethod (node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:382:33)
at QueryBuilder.addOperationUsingMethod (node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:413:28)
at QueryBuilder.addOperation (node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilderOperationSupport.js:404:22)
at /home/node/app/node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:709:12
at writeOperation (node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:1317:5)
at QueryBuilder.patch (node_modules/objection/lib/queryBuilder/QueryBuilder.js:706:12)
at UserDevicesConsumer.handleKafkaMessage (lib/kafka/consumers/userDevices.js:61:47)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Context.<anonymous> (test/kafka/consumer/userDevices.test.js:95:9)

This is the code I am using to update the model
await UserDevices.query().patch(device.id, {deleted_at: new Date().toISOString()});
and this is the schema of my model
const { Model } = require('objection');

class UserDevices extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
        return 'user_devices';
    }

    static get idColumn() {
        return 'id';
    }

    static get jsonSchema() {
        return {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
                id: { type: 'number' },
                device_id: { type: 'number' }
            }
        };
    }
}

module.exports = UserDevices;

I have spent hours trying to figure this out but to no avail

You are getting an error because the patch method expects one parameter which should be an object.
Change
await UserDevices.query().patch(device.id, {deleted_at: new Date().toISOString()});

to
await UserDevices.query().findById(device.id).patch({deleted_at: new Date().toISOString()});

and that should fix the issue
